# Is it possible to filter integer texture in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, textures, webgl2, webgl-extensions

I have read other posts (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421544/sampling-integer-texture-in-webgl-returns-weird-values)) that shows how to render integer texture (R16I) via WebGL.

However, it is using the gl.NEAREST for texture filtering for minification and magnification

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

I'm interested in using gl.LINEAR for filtering which is not supported apparently. Anyone know any workaround for this?

I found [EXT_texture_norm16](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_texture_norm16) which apparently adds rendering TO the texture, but not texture filtering? I'm not sure... (it didn't work with gl.LINEAR when I used it)

Comment: I didn't do extensive research but I suspect it's not possible and you'll have to filter it manually